# How to get data into cell by excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
{
    "declines": 143.0,
    "data": [{
        "symbol": "VISESHINFO",
        "xDt": "-",
        "caAct": "-",
        "iep": "0.10",
        "chn": "-0.05",
        "perChn": "-33.33",
        "pCls": "0.15",
        "trdQnty": "2,000",
        "iVal": "0.00",
        "mktCap": "-",
        "yHigh": "-",
        "yLow": "-",
        "sumVal": "5,629.00",
        "sumQnty": "16,66,005",
        "finQnty": "2,000",
        "sumfinQnty": "47,53,417"
    }, {
        "symbol": "NUTEK",
        "xDt": "-",
        "caAct": "-",
        "iep": "1.10",
        "chn": "0.15",
        "perChn": "15.79",
        "pCls": "0.95",
        "trdQnty": "26,312",
        "iVal": "0.29",
        "mktCap": "-",
        "yHigh": "-",
        "yLow": "-",
        "sumVal": "5,629.00",
        "sumQnty": "16,66,005",
        "finQnty": "26,312",
        "sumfinQnty": "47,53,417"
    }, {
        "symbol": "ORIENTALTL",
        "xDt": "-",
        "caAct": "-",
        "iep": "10.50",
        "chn": "-0.80",
        "perChn": "-7.08",
        "pCls": "11.30",
        "trdQnty": "250",
        "iVal": "0.03",
        "mktCap": "-",
        "yHigh": "-",
        "yLow": "-",
        "sumVal": "5,629.00",
        "sumQnty": "16,66,005",
        "finQnty": "250",
        "sumfinQnty": "47,53,417"
    }]
}
```

I only want some words in excel sheet e.g.
from above data in "A1 = VISESHINFO" in "A2 = NUTEK" in cell "A3 = ORIENTALTL"

Please some one help me.
I am new to this type. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need a JSON parser. [This](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) is the first result on Google, and sounds like it should do the trick.

Comment: Actually I really don't know. Please give me a hint. I dont know what is JSON parser. And how it will help me in excel VBA

Comment: The data you've posted is JSON, which VBA doesn't have any built-in libraries to process. You *could* try to interpret it by looking for the text that appears after `"symbol": "`, but that's generally a bad idea, so you'd be better off importing a tool which is designed to handle it.

Comment: JSON data looks like `{"key1","value1","key2":"value2"}`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON_sample

Comment: @jsheeran, Agree, there's no built-in libraries in VBA, but there's an alternative: [Github VBA-JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using the MS Script Control:

```
Sub TestJSONParsing()
    'requires reference to "Miscosoft Script Control 1.0"
    Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl, i, n
    Set oScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

    'create a js object in the scriptengine
    '(loading json from a worksheet cell)
    oScriptEngine.Eval ("var json=(" + Range("A8").Value + ")")

    n = oScriptEngine.Eval("json.data.length") '<< how many items in "data"?
    'loop over and extract the symbols...
    For i = 1 To n
        Debug.Print oScriptEngine.Eval("json.data[" & (i - 1) & "].symbol")
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a solution, that I have built so far. It can work definitely better and it can be updated further, but so far it works.

- First make sure that you copy the whole data and put it in one cell.
- Select the column
- Run the Sub TestMe()
- Try to make it better

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Public Sub TestMe()

      Debug.Print GetMeSomeData(Selection, "symbol", 1)
      Debug.Print GetMeSomeData(Selection, "symbol", 2)
      Debug.Print GetMeSomeData(Selection, "symbol", 3)

  End Sub

  Function GetMeSomeData(strData1 As String, _
                     strData2 As String, _
                     lngRepeat As Long) _
                              As String

  Dim arrTotal As Variant
  Dim varText As Variant
  Dim lngPosition As Long
  Dim lngResult As Long
  Dim lngFound As Long

  arrTotal = Split(strData1)

  For Each varText In arrTotal
      lngPosition = lngPosition + 1
      varText = Replace(Replace(varText, ":", ""), """", "")

      If varText = strData2 Then
          lngFound = lngFound + 1

          If lngFound = lngRepeat Then lngResult = lngPosition
      End If

  Next varText

  GetMeSomeData = arrTotal(lngResult)


  End Function
  ```

This is what you get in the immediate window:

```
"VISESHINFO",

"NUTEK",

"ORIENTALTL",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend to use: [VBA-JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) avalible on GitHub. Follow the link to get sample code and video tutorial.

Code from related site:

```
' Advanced example: Read .json file and load into sheet (Windows-only)
' (add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime)
' {"values":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c": 3},...]}

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Dim JsonText As String
Dim Parsed As Dictionary

' Read .json file
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("example.json", ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close

' Parse json to Dictionary
' "values" is parsed as Collection
' each item in "values" is parsed as Dictionary
Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)

' Prepare and write values to sheet
Dim Values As Variant
ReDim Values(Parsed("values").Count, 3)

Dim Value As Dictionary
Dim i As Long

i = 0
For Each Value In Parsed("values")
  Values(i, 0) = Value("a")
  Values(i, 1) = Value("b")
  Values(i, 2) = Value("c")
  i = i + 1
Next Value

Sheets("example").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Parsed("values").Count, 3)) = Values
```